# Can the Microsoft Azure Storage Table query results filtering by property value

Tags: c#, sql, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I am currently learning the Azure storage table. I did some learning from http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-table-storage-20/

It seems a key/value pair storage. It has partition key, row key, and include up to 252 properties.

From the link above, it can only filter the query result by row key. Can we query the result by filtering one of the property.

My project is to migrate our current sql database to the Azure storage table.

Current SQL database has three columns

Column a, Column b, Column c

Currently, our function need to support to query both by filtering column a and column b. When we migrate to Azure storage table, we need to keep the function

I think we only can set one of the two columns as the row key and the others should be in the properties of the Azure table. Also I don't think the column b can be the row key since it can not uniquely identify a row in our previous sql table (My understanding is correct?)

So can I query by both Column a and b if I only set column a as the row key and column b as a property when I migrate the table to Azure storage. If not, is there any suggestions to solve it?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can filter by any attribute. However please keep in mind that only PartitionKey and RowKey are indexed thus any query operation which doesn't include at least PartitionKey will result in full table scan. This will become an issue if your table contains lots of entities.